# Forward search from Emacs (AUCTeX) to Okular with \include not working

Tags: emacs, auctex, include, forward-inverse-search, okular

Forward search from Emacs (AUCTeX) to Okular with `\include` is not working. My OS:

```
OS: Debian bullseye (testing)  
Emacs: 26.3
Okular: 1.11.1
AUCTeX: 12.2.4
```

.emacs (Emacs settings):

```
(custom-set-variables                                                                                                                                   
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (auctex)))                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                         
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))                                                                                                                                          
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)                                                                                                                                                          
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)                                                                                                                                                  
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b"))))                                                                                                             
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((engine-omega "dvips and gv") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-pdf "Okular") (output-html "xdg-open"))))                                                
)
```

./main.tex:

```
\documentclass{}
\begin{document}
\include{chapters/chap1}
\end{document}
```

./chapters/chap1.tex:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Blub 1.1}
\subsection{Blub 1.1.1}
```

`C-c C-v` (= shortcut for forward searching from Emacs to Okular) on line `\section{Blub 1.1}` gives me the (emacs) error:

```
Output file "chap1.pdf" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting the following text (especially `%%% TeX-master: "../master.tex"`) at the end of my chapter files (e.g. chap1.tex) fixed my problem:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../master.tex"
%%% End:
```